# German equivalents of “in my first year”

Tags: english-to-german, time

I'm thinking about the sentence

> In my first year, I lived in an apartment.

where I simply mean that my place of residence during my first year (of college) was an apartment. I'm wondering what time expression is best to match this in German. Some options I've considered:

> 1. Mein erstes Jahr habe ich in einer Wohnung gewohnt.
> 2. In meinem ersten Jahr habe ich in einer Wohnung gewohnt.
> 3. Während meines ersten Jahres habe ich in einer Wohnung gewohnt.

Does one stick out as the best?

Comment: Actually the *my* has no strong need of being translated into German. *Im ersten Jahr [in München] habe ich in einer Wohnung gewohnt* is perfectly sufficient.

Comment: Definitiv Auswahl 3.

Comment: Oder: Während meines ersten Jahres lebte ich in einer Wohnung.

Comment: Oder^2: Für das erste Jahr lebte ich ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich hoffe, es ist ok wenn ich auf Deutsch antworte. Bei Bedarf liefere ich gerne eine englische Übersetzung nach.

Das Verb »*wohnen*« ist ein intransitives Verb. Das heißt, man kann zwar wohnen, aber man kann nicht *etwas* wohnen.

- intransitiver Gebrauch eines Verbs:

  > Ich schreibe.
  >   Ich schreibe in meinem Zimmer.
  >   Ich schreibe am Nachmittag in meinem Zimmer.
- transitiver Gebrauch eines Verbs:

  > Ich schreibe **einen Aufsatz**.
  >   Ich schreibe **einen Aufsatz** in meinem Zimmer.
  >   Ich schreibe am Nachmittag **einen Aufsatz** in meinem Zimmer.

Das Verb »wohnen« kann nur intransitiv verwendet werden:

> Ich wohne.
>   Ich wohne in einem Haus.
>   Ich wohne mit meiner Familie in einem Haus.

Das Verb »wohnen« transitiv zu gebrauchen ist ein Fehler:

> Falsch: Ich wohne ein Jahr.

Anders formuliert: Das Verb »wohnen« kann kein Akkusativobjekt haben. Genau das ist aber in deinem ersten Satz der Fall:

> Falsch: **Mein erstes Jahr** habe ich in einer Wohnung gewohnt.

»Mein erstes Jahr« ist ein Akkusativobjekt, und das passt nicht zu »wohnen«.

Die beiden anderen Beispiele sind in Ordnung, denn hier ist das erste Satzglied kein Akkusativobjekt, sondern ein Adverbial (auch »adverbiale Bestimmung« genannt), in diesem Fall ein Temporaladverbial.

---

### Nachtrag:

Nach Temporaladverbialen kann man immer mit der Frage »wann?« fragen:

> **Wann** hast du in einer Wohnung gewohnt?
>   **In meinem ersten Jahr**
>
> **Wann** hast du in einer Wohnung gewohnt?
>   **Während meines ersten Jahres**

Andere Beispiele:

> **Wann** gehts du in Rente?
>   **Nächstes Jahr**
>
> **Wann** ist dein Geburtstag?
>   **Übermorgen**

Aber »Mein erstes Jahr« ist keine Antwort auf eine Wann-Frage.

> **Wann** hast du in einer Wohnung gewohnt?
>   <del>*Mein erstes Jahr*</del>

»Mein erstes Jahr« ist aber eine gültige Antwort auf eine Was-Frage:

> **Was** hast du in einer Wohnung verbracht?
>   **Mein erstes Jahr**

Da man mit »was?« nach Akkusativobjekten fragt, ist »*mein erstes Jahr*« genau das: Ein Akkusativobjekt. Und als solches passt es leider nicht zum Verb »wohnen«.

Comment: Wer sagt das *Mein erstes Jahr* im ersten Fall ein Akkusativobjekt ist? Es ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit analog zu denen in »Nächstes Jahr gehe ich in Rente.« oder »Übermorgen ist mein Geburtstag.«.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Nach »Mein erstes Jahr« kann man nicht mit »wann?« fragen. Frage: »Wann hast du dort gewohnt?« Antwort: »Mein erstes Jahr.« Das passt nicht. Aber: »Was hast du dort verbracht?« - »Mein erstes Jahr.« Das ist Akkusativ! Das Problem dabei: »verbringen« erlaubt ein Akkusativobjekt, »wohnen« aber nicht. Daher würde schon die Frage nach dem Akkusativ einen Fehler enthalten: »Was hast du dort gewohnt?« - »Mein erstes Jahr.«

Comment: (Forts.:) Deine Beispiele kann man hingegen sehr wohl mit »wann?« erfragen: »Wann gehst du in Rente?« -  »Nächstes Jahr«. »Wann ist dein Geburtstag?« - »Übermorgen.«. Das sind adverbiale Bestimmungen. Aber auf die Frage »Wann hast du dort gewohnt?« kann niemals die Antwort »Mein erstes Jahr« kommen.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Ihre Antwort. Der erste Satz hat mir bestimmt falsch geklungen, aber ich wusste nicht warum. Ich dachte genauso wie @Wrzlprmft.

Comment: @user33698, "Der erste Satz hat mir bestimmt falsch geklungen" kann man so nicht sagen. Richtig wären zum Beispiel "Für mich hat der Satz falsch geklungen" oder "(Ich fand,) der Satz hat falsch geklungen" oder "Mir kam der Satz komisch vor"

Comment: @Iris, ist das denn nicht der »dative of interest«, z.B. wie »Mir geht's gut.«?

Comment: @user33698, ich kenne den »dative of interest« nicht. Ich habe nur auf mein Sprachgefühl als Muttersprachler gehört. Wenn du es genau wissen willst, stellst du am besten eine eigene Frage dafür. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two general issues here, one of which (the grammar and required preposition) was covered well by [Hubert’s answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/34843).

The second issue is the choice of words. Unfortunately, [college](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College) in itself is slightly ambiguous and can mean anything from [a boarding school for general secondary education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eton_College), [a school that takes pupils with GCSE and keeps them until they gain their A-levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_form_college) over to [a subdivision of a university](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_London#Colleges) right up to [a synonym for university](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/College). Depending on what you mean when you say *college* will, unfortunately, also modify the choice of expression.

Anything that is secondary education — i.e. anything from the list above that will lead to an *Abitur,* A-level or equivalent — or vocational education *(Berufsschule* and related instutitions) is typically organised in *school years* in Germany with *terms* (two a year, adequately termed *Halbjahr)* being of minor importance. For those the imho best translation of *first year* would be:

> In meinem ersten **Schuljahr** (der Berufsschule/gymnasialen Oberstufe, etc.)
>
> Während meines ersten **Schuljahrs** (an der Berufsschule/gymnasialen Oberstufe, etc)

Anything that considers itself tertiary education — most notably universities — is typically organised into *semesters* that compose the students’ time reference. Instead of talking about first year, students would talk about their first two semesters. The most notable exception are the [Universities of the *Bundeswehr*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_the_German_Federal_Armed_Forces), whose academic year is divided into three trimesters rather than two semesters. Two academic years at that institution correspond to three academic years at other universities.

Since *Semester* is such a strong word for students, if you are talking about tertiary education the best translation would not use years but:

> In meinen ersten beiden **Semestern** …
>
> Während meiner ersten beiden **Semester** …

---

This answer mainly presents the situation in Germany. In Switzerland and Austria, it may differ especially with regards to secondary education.